# viewport unit doesn't work for HybridWebView in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Here is the official example from Xamarin for hybridWebView
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView

If I add a div into [index.html](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView/Droid/Assets/Content/index.html)

like

```html
<div class="test" style="height: 50vh; background-color: green;">this is a test</div>
```

The viewport unit doesn't work

I think it is because there is no viewport for this webview. I wonder if there is a way to make it work.

We tried it on emulator and a real device (8.0)
[image: screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: What is the version of your Android ?

Comment: api level > 23.

Comment: Did you add ``` <meta name="viewport" content="width =device-width,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">``` in **head** ?

Comment: Yes. it works if I just use webview, but I want to use HybridWebView solution.

Comment: You just need to add the above line in index.html . It is same between webview and HybridWebView

Comment: It doesn't work. That was actually the first thing I tried before asking the question. I thought it should be the same between webview and HybridWebView but it is not.

Comment: HybridWebView works fine in my project.  Can you share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView/ download the simple and add the line in the index.html like I said in my question and you will see the issue.

Comment: I did the same thing and works fine on my device (Android 8.1). So you can use other device or emulator and test again .

Comment: Really? Do you see test div with **green** background? We tested it on VS2017/9 and 2 different machines and devices.

Comment: Yes, it works fine on Android 8.0 and 8.1 . Can you provide the content of index.html .

Comment: Just put it together in a repo https://github.com/Sam-Lin-MillersLab/HybridWebViewExample There should be a green block.

Comment: I will check it .If it is a existing bug , I will add it on github of Xamarin .

Comment: I actually posted one there already https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6819

Comment: OK, we will focus on it.

Comment: So did you try it? Can you repeat the issue now?

Comment: Yes, and the thread seems had been closed now ,you can check it.

Comment: yeah, I know. I don't understand why he said " HybridWebView is a sample on how to create a custom renderer, not a fully fledged control we support or distribute." I feel like Xamarin might not be the framework I should stick with.

Comment: I think it is the issue of webview on Android .

Comment: maybe. But I think Xamarin should handle it.